# Can I vote on deleted answer

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers, upvotes

I see now deleted answers and it seems I can vote (up/down) on it.

Is it ethical to vote on answer that a user choose to delete and expect to be ignored by its peers?

When should I vote on deleted answer? can I really treat it as regular answer regarding if it is helpful to me?

Will the vote effect user reputation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't vote on deleted answers.

It might look like you can, but that's just the client reacting to your interaction with the JavaScript on the page. Nothing is sent to the server.

If you refresh the page you'll see that the vote has remained unchanged.

Comment: If you vote on a deleted answer it just pops up an error message saying you can't vote on deleted answers.

Comment: Can I add an enhancement to remove the option in the UI? it's a bit confusing

Comment: @user7294900 Create a meta question suggesting that as a feature-request if you want. Bear in mind that people who disagree that developers should spend their time implementing this (as opposed to implementing something more valuable) will downvote your question.

Comment: @user7294900 I don't see how it's more confusing than showing the vote buttons on your own posts.

Comment: That doesn't make it right...